# How to get around “Detected ambiguous Field Reference” when parsing HTTP URL parameters with Logstash

Tags: apache, get, logstash

So I have been using Logstash to parse Apache access logs. Currently I am using some [`kv`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filters to handle this with Logstash 6.7.x (and earlier) with but wanted to upgrade to Logstash 7.x.

It seems like a warning I have been seeing in Logstash 6.7.x is now resulting in an outright failure with an “Exception” that renders `kv` my filters useless.

The warning I get in Logstash 6.7.0 is this:

```
2019-05-13T10:57:09,541][WARN ][org.logstash.FieldReference] Detected ambiguous Field Reference `fee[]`, which we expanded to the path `[fee]`; in a future release of Logstash, ambiguous Field References will not be expanded.
```

The `kv` filters look like this:

```
kv {
  source => "request"
  field_split => "&?"
  allow_duplicate_values => false
  include_keys => [ "fee", "fie", "foe", "fum" ]
  include_keys => [ "fee[]", "fie[]", "foe[]", "fum[]" ]
  prefix => "abc_"
}
```

Yes, it looks like the [`include_keys`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-include_keys) are slightly redundant, but if you know about GET parameters in a URL, including things like `fee` and `fee[]` allow me to capture values to are passed as an array as well as a string. And it has been working great! Until now.

In Logstash 7.x, instead of getting a warning I get the following:

```
Exception while parsing KV {:exception=>"Invalid FieldReference: `fee[]`"}
```

Well, that stinks. It basically means that my `fee[]` key include fails. And now my data parsing is off since I need to account for values that are sent as `fee` as well as `fee[]` in this process.

Reading that warning from Logstash 6.7.x seems to clearly state that `fee[]` will be interpreted as `[fee]` but that is utterly not what I need since GET URL parameters don’t really assign array values of `fee[0]`, `fee[1]` and `fee[2]` and such; the values are fairly arbitrary for items based on user input.

So what can I do to effectively get past this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I read up on this issue on [this discussion thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/detected-ambiguous-field-reference-warnings-in-logstash-6-4-0/149825) on the official Elasticsearch website. It lead me to [this documentation reference](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/7.x/docs/static/field-reference.asciidoc) which helps… But only confirms what I stated when I said `fee[]` will be interpreted as `[fee]` which won’t work for me.

So I reviewed my code as well as the [`kv`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) field options and realized that—for my purposes—I was doing this all wrong: Instead of having two lines of [`include_keys`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-include_keys)—which is redundant and clearly not ideal—I should be using [`remove_char_key`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-remove_char_key) to get rid of the square brackets like this:

```
remove_char_key => "\[\]"
```

And integrated into my `kv` filters, it would look like this:

```
kv {
  source => "request"
  field_split => "&?"
  allow_duplicate_values => false
  remove_char_key => "\[\]"
  include_keys => [ "fee", "fie", "foe", "fum" ]
  prefix => "abc_"
}
```

Doing basic testing between these adjusted `kv` filters and what I had in place before show 100% same desired results and output. So all good to go! And with this in place I can safely upgrade to Logstash 7.x.